# Moving to a screen without adding it to createTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have created two screens ('search' and 'Add') using createTabNavigator. However, I'd like to make 'Add' a step by step process, where you fill out some details, click next fill out other fields etc. However, I'm not sure how to navigate to these screens without first adding them to createTabNavigator.

The problem with this is that it adds the screens to the tabs which I'm not looking for (they are supposed to be hidden).

I just wondered if anyone had any recommendations on how to approach this. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar situation, there is a very simple solution for this.
Writing the Navigator in a nested format with a stack navigator will help you hide it and also navigate in react-navigation.

For Example, I'm using a tab navigator with Home Container and so Registration Screens which should be hidden from the tabs;

```
      export const HomeContainer = createBottomTabNavigator({
      Loan: {
        screen: createStackNavigator({
          Home: {
            screen: Home,
            navigationOptions: {
              header: null,
              gesturesEnabled: false
            }
          },
          Register1: {
            screen: R1,
            navigationOptions: {
              header: null,
              gesturesEnabled: false
            }
          },
          Register-2: {
            screen: R2,
            navigationOptions: {
              header: null,
              gesturesEnabled: false
            }
          },
        }),
        navigationOptions: {
          title: "Home",
          tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: '#D72163',
            inactiveTintColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.54)',
            gesturesEnabled: false
          },
       }
     }
   });
```

Here, I have written a Home Container with 2 register screens. The register screens are written in stack navigator inside the tab navigator of Home.

For further clarifications, comment here.

Comment: That's great, many thanks for sharing Krishnaraj R that worked perfectly! :)